# Flask HTMX Can't grab dropdown value twice

Tags: python, flask, htmx

I'm trying to have the native text dropdown affect the language of the values of the other dropdowns:

[image]

I can't seem to find if there's a way to do multiple hx-target values, so the idea was that I was going to daisy chain it, after selecting native, I'll select learning text, and learning text will trigger the learning audio but look at the Native text for the language of values.

It works between native text and learning text, but when I do this between learning text and learning audio the same code for request.args.get('native_txt_dropdown') returns None now. Any idea how to the hell to make this work? For some reason I'm spending hours on what's supposed to be this easy project.

```
@app.route("/learning_text_dropdown", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def learning_text_dropdown():
    global  language_dropdowns_dic
    native_language_selection = request.args.get('native_txt_dropdown') #Gets the first selection from user

    print("NATIVE SELECTION:")
    print(native_language_selection)

    #Populate the other dropdowns according to the native language selected:
    if native_language_selection != None:
        learning_language_selection = language_dropdowns_dic['learning_text'][native_language_selection]

    return render_template('learning_text_dropdown.html',
                           learning_language_selection = learning_language_selection,
                           native_language_selection = native_language_selection)




@app.route("/learning_audio_dropdown", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def learning_audio_dropdown():
    global language_dropdowns_dic
    global native_language_selection
    print("Entered Dropdown audio")
    native_language_selection = request.args.get('native_txt_dropdown')  # Gets the first selection from user
    #native_language_selection = "Spanish - Español"
    print(native_language_selection)
    # Populate the other dropdowns according to the native language selected:
    #audio_language_selection = {}
    if native_language_selection != None:
        audio_language_selection = language_dropdowns_dic['learning_audio'][native_language_selection]


    return render_template('learning_audio_dropdown.html',

                           audio_language_selection=audio_language_selection,


                           )
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Woe to the Conquered Learnig App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <header class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__brand">
      <img class="navbar__logo" src="/static/logo.svg" alt="The Microblog logo" />Woe to the Conquered Learnig App
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar__navigation">
      <li class="navbar__navigation-item">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__link">Recent</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__navigation-item">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__link">Calendar</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <section>
      <h3>Select App Options:</h3>

        <label id="native_txt_label" value="en" default=5 for="label native text"> {{ native_txt_label}}:   </label>

      <select id="native_txt_dropdown" name="native_txt_dropdown" hx-trigger="change, load" hx-get="/learning_text_dropdown"  hx-target="#learning_txt_dropdown">
          <option value={{short_instructions}}>{{short_instructions}}</option>
          {% for name,id in language_main_dropdown.items() %}
          <option {% if selected == id %}selected{% endif %} value="{{ name }}">
            {{name|safe}}
          </option>
          {% endfor %}
            </select>

        </br>

        <label id="learning_txt_label" for="label learning text"> {{learning_txt_label}}:   </label>

      <select id="learning_txt_dropdown" name="learning_txt_dropdown" hx-trigger="change, load" hx-get="/learning_audio_dropdown"  hx-target="#learning_txt_audio">
            <option value={{short_instructions}}>{{short_instructions}}</option>
          {% for name,id in learning_language_selection.items() %}
          <option {% if selected == id %}selected{% endif %} value="{{ id }}">
            {{name|safe}}
          </option>
          {% endfor %}

            </select>
        </br>


        <label id="learning_audio_label"  for="label learning audio"> {{learning_audio_label}}:   </label>

        <select id="learning_txt_audio" name="learning_txt_audio" hx-trigger="change, load" hx-get="/learning_recording_dropdown"  hx-target="#learning_txt_recording">

            <option value="en">English </option>
            <option value="ru">Russian </option>
            <option value="fr">French </option>
            <option value="es">Spanish </option>


            </select>
        </br>




        <label id="learning_recording_label" for="label recording audio">{{learning_recording_label}}:  </label>

        <select id="learning_txt_recording" name="learning_txt_recording" hx-trigger="change, load" >

            <option value="en-US">English (United States) </option>
            <option value="es-MX">Spanish (Mexico) </option>
            <option value="fr-FR">French (France) </option>
            <option value="ru-RU">Russian (Russia) </option>

            </select>
        </br>








        <p></p>








      <form class="form" method="POST">



























        <p class="form__input">
          <label id="short_instructions" for="entry" class="form__label">{{short_instructions}}</label>
          <textarea name="content" id="entry" class="form__textarea"></textarea>
        </p>
        <button type="submit" class="form__submit">Add entry</button>

      </form>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>Recent posts</h1>
      {% for entry in entries %}
        <article class="entry">
          <div>
            <h2 class="entry__title">{{ entry[0] | truncate(30, true) }}</h2>
            <time class="entry__date" datetime="{{ entry[1] }}">• {{ entry[2] }}</time>
          </div>
          <p class="entry__content">
            {{ entry[0] }}
          </p>
        </article>
      {% endfor %}
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer__content">
      <section class="left">
        <a class="footer__item">Made by Jose Salvatierra</a>
        <a class="footer__item">Check out my other projects</a>
      </section>
      <section class="right">
        <div class="footer__column">
          <a class="footer__item">Recent</a>
          <a class="footer__item">Calendar</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer__column">
          <a class="footer__item" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="footer__item">How this was made</a>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </footer>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.7.0"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMX support multiple targets via [out of band swapping](https://htmx.org/docs/#oob_swaps). In the response HTML you just need to add `hx-swap-oob="true"` to the select inputs, e.g.:

```
<select id="learning_txt_dropdown" hx-swap-oob="true">...</select>
<select id="learning_audio_label" hx-swap-oob="true">...</select>
<select id="learning_txt_recording" hx-swap-oob="true">...</select>
```

HTMX will swap the respective selects. Or simply you can just group these dropdowns into a common div so you only need one target to swap.

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know about the div trick either, I'll give it a try! I was starting to remake the app already, it's not as intuitive as tkinter